# AngularJs - debugging failed $http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am debugging a large angularjs app that I didn't write, and I'm having issues with failed http requests made with `$http`, all I get in the console is:

> `<http method> <url> <error code>`

And the line points to `angular:8632`. Is there a way to understand where is the attempted http call happening? If not, is there any best practice that can be implemented to make it easier to debug?

Comment: You know failed URL => just check corresponding module/service/controller.

Comment: I tried that, it appears as if one module calls another, I only know which module is required but not which one is making the request

Comment: if you are on chrome, this might help - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang-stable/niopocochgahfkiccpjmmpchncjoapek

Comment: On Chrome, in development tools. Find http request in Network. You can read headers and so on

Comment: Im ashamed to say, but software downloads are blocked it my workplace so I cant get batarang. Regarding the http headers, couldnt find any useful information there

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, you could try setting breakpoints. You can find a tutorial [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). Other browsers will definitely support this too, but I have no experience with them.

For best practices, you should look into test-driven development. There are lots of articles about this on the web.

An example:

- [unit-testing-best-practices-angularjs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)

The basic idea is that you first develop a test on wich your code has to succeed. Then you write the code until the test succeeds. If someone else changes te code en breaks something, you can easily find out where the bug is with the tests.